# How do android games like farmville count time, even when the app is closed?

Tags: android, timer

How do android games like farmville count time, even when the app is closed? As in to grow a plant, etc.

Answer (score 1):

(its been a while, so might be wrong)

but what we done was get sys time, and compare with value originally stored.